# Find radius from centroid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, polygons, rgeo

I'm converting a KML file to a polygon stored on my database thanks to `RGeo`

I need the centroid: `@area.centroid` and I would like to find the approximative radius on my shape.
I don't know if it's possible. My database field is a `geometry`. That means I can store polygons AND multi-polygons. The type of my area is `RGeo::Geos::CAPIMultiPolygonImpl`

Finally I think I need the check if the area is a simple polygon or a multiple. If it's a simple one, I would like to find the radius. Else nothing.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: See [ST_MinimumBoundingCircle](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html)

Comment: It seems to be that but I'm not able to call this method through active-record with my `CAPIMultiPolygonImpl` variable type. Do you have another tip ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The [somewhat readable code for ST_MinimumBoundingCircle](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/trunk/postgis/postgis.sql.in#L4984) shows the underlying logic that might give some ideas. For instance, it does a brute force distance search between each pair of points of the convex hull. You could simplify this to just the exterior ring and the centroid.

Comment: I can't do an exterior ring because I'm working with `MultiPolygon` type. I could find each radius of each polygon and add this to the largest distance to one of the centroids. I'll take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: You could take the convex hull of a multipolygon to get an exterior ring of a polygon.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with a multipolygon but I'll look at it. Thank you for this very good idea.

Comment: Any geometry type can have a convex hull.

Comment: Could you utilize anything from `ST_Centroid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did like below:

1. Convexe Hull
2. Centroid of this Convexe Hull
3. minimum distance between Convexe Hull points (thanks to `exterior_ring` function) and the centroid

By the way I don't know why I had to take the minimum. It was to adapt my scale. I don't really understand how the centroid of a polygon (which could have really strange shape) can be found.

Anyway, it's working thanks to the 3 steps written previously.